# How to assign different colors for parent and child nodes in Bootstrap 4 scroll spy?

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

In the example on the link below, when a child is selected, the background color of the child and its parent become the same color. To me, this is a bit confusing. Is there a way to have the child (active) link have a different background color than the parent's background color? In the example they are both blue, what if I wanted the parent to be ligth-gray and the active child blue? Thanks.

[Bootstrap 4.x Scrollspy - Example with nested navs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/#example-with-nested-nav)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by overriding the parent active link, and then "reset" the default blue on the children using the CSS next sibling (+) selector on on the inner .nav-pills links...

```
/* parent gray */
.nav-pills .nav-link.active,
.nav-pills .nav-link:hover,
.nav-pills .nav-link:focus {
    background-color: grey;
}

/* child default blue */
.nav-pills .nav-link + .nav .nav-link.active {
    background-color: #007bff;
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/lfU9NTAETj

Comment: Thank your for the details and for taking the time to write the full code....Very useful to me. Thank you much.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use CSS an change it manually like this and them all the active childs come to other color:

```
a.nav-link.ml-3.my-1.active {
background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Correct answer indeed. I had to mark the other entry as an answer because it provided extra information that I found useful, however your answer is complete and correct indeed. Thank you very much.